# MYSQL: Best approach for storing Event Log

Tags: mysql, relational-database, document-oriented-db

We all know that MYSQL is a relational database; And in the application that I am going to write, I need to use a relational database mainly because of sharing information between entities and joins on tables.

But I also have a very special condition, I need to keep track of some of events happening in the application. For example, lets say that I have a 'User' table with a field named 'XP', now I want to keep all the events resulted in change of 'XP' for this user.

Well, the most simple solution would be creating a new table and storing the events with a field pointing to the responsible user. But this tables gets overwhelmingly big and fills with unnecessarily rows, slowing the whole application.

If I was on a document oriented database, this wasn't a problem of course, but with MYSQL this tends to make everything slow.

I want to know your opinions here for possible ways to solve the problem and still keep the performance in a reasonable range. I didn't found any research or article related in the net.

PS, I had this idea about saving the changes as a JSON array in a field (of 'User' table), but then reading a field, converting it from text, adding an item and saving it again is very unpractical.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have an incredibly large volume of data, indexes and partitioning will probably solve your problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, well Gordon, it is going to be like 1 to 2 millions of records per day. Maybe more if we gets more users after a while. Data is short, mainly some integers. Reading is rare, happens only for reporting and maintenance. But as these events happens in different parts of the application, any slow down in this table results in slow down of whole application. I am sure its no gonna make things bad for first millions or even billions of rows, but what eventually? After some years? I know MYSQL is not good with big tables. It wasn't in the 4.x and early 5.x era at least.

Comment: 15-30 inserts per second is not incredibly large and MySQL should be able to handle that.  As for this having an effect on the table as it gets bigger, partitioning probably fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

What kinds of events are you keeping track of?  Maybe it would be more practical to use a trigger to create events (so you don't have to do it manually on inserts/updates/etc).  I'd also consider trying to separate the events based on the data you're dealing with into event-centric tables to reduce the amount of data you have to deal with on a given relationship (ex. a LOGIN_EVENT table that relates to a USER table on a USER_ID key, then a separate REPORT_REQUEST_EVENT table related to USER on the same key).  By separating concerns you can create a more performant structure.

Comment: The events are not of important much. So separating them just makes the reading so harder. The information that are going to be saved are simply an ID, an Integer to show the event (enum type), an integer to show that change amount and a time stamp along with a field for userid.

Comment: The join will be more DB-intensive if you don't segregate the events.